# How to calculate the volume of air that will cool steel?

Tags: thermodynamics, cooling

The task is to cool steel pieces in boxes with **indoor air** using a fan.
The number of boxes is **6 pcs**, each weighs about **15 kg**.
It is required to cool them **from 90°C to 30°C** with using **30°C air in 9 min**.

EDIT 2:

As I was advised, I tried to calculate the SHC:

[image]

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: If this is homework then you'll need to show your work. First task: calculate the energy to be removed from the steel. For this you're going to have to look up its specific heat capacity (SHC). [Edit] it into your question.

Comment: OK, so you've got to extract 5.5 MJ. How many kg of air will that take? (Same procedure.) Actually, where did you get your SHC value from? It doesn't look right.

Comment: I found this online calculator and just tried to put values: [link](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/specific-heat) .. What did I forget to take into account?

Comment: Look up the SHC of steel. It's not 1012 J/(kg-K). You've chosen air.

Comment: And what do u mean (same procedure.)? It's still unclear to me :( .. How do I incorporate the time (9 mins) it should take to cool down?

Comment: I'm stepping you through the procedure. I was bringing you onto calculating the mass of air required when I noticed that your first calculation is not correct. You have to calculate the energy to be removed from **the steel** first. You've used the SCH for **air** instead. Start again.

Comment: oh I overlooked that.. I changed to steel.. there is new result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127687/discussion-between-transistor-and-ghostix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Calculate the **heat** to be extracted from the steel. You'll need to look up the SHC of steel.
2. Calculate what **mass** of 30°C air will be required to absorb that much heat.
3. Calculate the **volume** of that mass of air. That answers the question in your question title.
4. **Flow rate** is volume / time.

Answer (score 0):

Specific heat capacity of steel is 0.466. In other words it takes 0.466 joules to raise the temperature of one gram of steel one degree Celsius. So how hot is the steel initially. In your case 90 degrees to get down to 30 you must remove from 90,000 grams, or 2.5 megajoules.

Forced air cooling for example of electronics electronic components use fan cooling. Makers of fans fans and compressors must consider the relationship between fan or impeller speed in rpm (revolutions per minute) and volumetric air flow in CFM (cubic feet per minute).